# Compatibilidad con el navegador

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, vite, typeerror

Instalé algunas dependencias para usar *Font Awesome* en mi aplicación de React con Vite y me genera el siguiente error en consola:

[image: Error generado en consola]

Esto hace que no se muestre ninguna vista de mi aplicación. ¿Cómo podría solucionar esto?

Comment: en el enlace de abajo encontre algo de informacion, esta en ingles pero es corto y se entiende: https://dev.to/0xbf/vite-module-path-has-been-externalized-for-browser-compatibility-2bo6

Comment: Me atrevería a decir que es porque has intentado ejecutar tu proyecto sin compilarlo, es decir, que no se está ejecutando en ningún entorno. Prueba a ejecutarlo son el live server de Visual Studio Code, o configurando un servidor Apache con tu aplicación.

Comment: Dependiendo de tu package.json, talvez te falte hacer un `npm run build`